# Create 10 second grid/graticule ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, grids-graticules

I am looking for a way to create a 10 second graticule/grid. I have north west corner coordinates where the grid should start from and spread out based on 10 second intervals. I have looked at two arcmap tools but they didn't work for me. The "Grid Index Features" tool worked well except for the fact that it places my starting coordinates at the south west corner and I don't see an option to have it start in the north west. The "Create Fishnet" tool parameters are shown below but they result in a fishnet which starts in the north east corner instead of the north west corner. I used Nad83 and converted 10 seconds to decimal degrees and used that as the cell size width and height.

[image: Fishnet parameters]

The green point is where I need the fishnet to start from and draw to the east but it by default, starts at the north east corner and draws to the west.
[image: Fishnet results]

Question 1. Is there a way to have the fishnet start drawing from the north west corner spreading east?
Question 2. How can I verify that the intervals are indeed 10 seconds apart?

Comment: What values did you set your origin and y axis coordinate to? If the y axis coordinate has the same x value as the origin, the grid shouldn't be rotated if displayed in degrees. If you're projecting the fishnet to a ProjCRS, then rotation will depend on the map projection. More info please!

Comment: Making the y axis x coordinate the same value as the origin x coordinate removes the rotation. Thanks for the tip. However, the origin is now placed at the north east corner but I need the origin to be at the north west corner.

Comment: Please do not comment on your own post. Comments are for *requests* for clarification, but the clarifications should be in the form of an [Edit] to the question. You need to provide the details of the Create Fishnet parameters for us to tell what you've done wrong. To echo Melita, more info please.

Comment: I can get the grid to build to the southwest or to the northeast (give a y coord axis value larger than the start point). I think somehow you're going to have to calculate the southwest corner as the start or the southeast corner as the opposite corner.

Comment: Have you tried using a negative number for the Cell Width to force it to the East?

Comment: @klewis Using a negative cell width forced it to the east. Thank you!!

Comment: Now I just need a way to verify that the intervals are indeed 10 seconds apart after the fishnet has been constructed.